# Get notified of successful/failed builds on Amazon's CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I'd like to build a tool that would notify a user each time there was a successful or failed build on CodeDeploy through any communication medium (email, slack, etc). I've went through their documentation.. and nothing except for long-polling comes to mind. Any idea if there's some webhook option where i can register a URL and be notified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update on 2016-04-27

AWS officially [announced this in February 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-notifications-for-aws-codedeploy-events/):

> You can now create triggers that send Amazon SNS notifications before, during, and after the deployment process for your applications. Triggers can be set for the deployment as a whole or for the individual instances targeted by the deployment, and are sent on both successes and failures.

### Original answer

**Not yet.**

In [this AWS forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=672271&#672271), it was requested that CodeDeploy emit events so you can use Lambda to process them instead of polling for details.

The answer by AWS staff (emphasis mine):

> We here on CodeDeploy agree.
>   Unfortunately, I can't give you an exact release date but keep an eye on our announcements, *it's coming soon.*

Comment: It's here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-slack-integration-blueprints-for-aws-lambda/

Comment: Take a look at the answer from Royce H for a working code snippet

Answer (score 3):

Here is a gist of an AWS Lambda function that posts a formatted CodeDeploy notification to Slack

https://gist.github.com/MrRoyce/097edc0de2fe001288be2e8633f4b22a

```js
var services = '/services/...';  // Update this with your Slack service...
var channel = "#aws-deployments"  // And this with the Slack channel

var https = require('https');
var util = require('util');

var formatFields = function(string) {
  var
    message = JSON.parse(string),
    fields  = [],
    deploymentOverview;

  // Make sure we have a valid response
  if (message) {
    fields = [
      {
        "title" : "Task",
        "value" : message.eventTriggerName,
        "short" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Status",
        "value" : message.status,
        "short" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Application",
        "value" : message.applicationName,
        "short" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Deployment Group",
        "value" : message.deploymentGroupName,
        "short" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Region",
        "value" : message.region,
        "short" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Deployment Id",
        "value" : message.deploymentId,
        "short" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Create Time",
        "value" : message.createTime,
        "short" : true
      },
      {
        "title" : "Complete Time",
        "value" : ((message.completeTime) ? message.completeTime : ''),
        "short" : true
      }
    ];

    if (message.deploymentOverview) {
     deploymentOverview = JSON.parse(message.deploymentOverview);
     
      fields.push(
        {
          "title" : "Succeeded",
          "value" : deploymentOverview.Succeeded,
          "short" : true
        },
        {
          "title" : "Failed",
          "value" : deploymentOverview.Failed,
          "short" : true
        },
        {
          "title" : "Skipped",
          "value" : deploymentOverview.Skipped,
          "short" : true
        },
        {
          "title" : "In Progress",
          "value" : deploymentOverview.InProgress,
          "short" : true
        },
        {
          "title" : "Pending",
          "value" : deploymentOverview.Pending,
          "short" : true
        }
      );
    }
  }

  return fields;

}

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var postData = {
        "channel": channel,
        "username": "AWS SNS via Lamda :: CodeDeploy Status",
        "text": "*" + event.Records[0].Sns.Subject + "*",
        "icon_emoji": ":aws:"
    };

    var fields = formatFields(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);
    var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
    var severity = "good";

    var dangerMessages = [
        " but with errors",
        " to RED",
        "During an aborted deployment",
        "FAILED",
        "Failed to deploy application",
        "Failed to deploy configuration",
        "has a dependent object",
        "is not authorized to perform",
        "Pending to Degraded",
        "Stack deletion failed",
        "Unsuccessful command execution",
        "You do not have permission",
        "Your quota allows for 0 more running instance"];

    var warningMessages = [
        " aborted operation.",
        " to YELLOW",
        "Adding instance ",
        "Degraded to Info",
        "Deleting SNS topic",
        "is currently running under desired capacity",
        "Ok to Info",
        "Ok to Warning",
        "Pending Initialization",
        "Removed instance ",
        "Rollback of environment"
        ];

    for(var dangerMessagesItem in dangerMessages) {
        if (message.indexOf(dangerMessages[dangerMessagesItem]) != -1) {
            severity = "danger";
            break;
        }
    }

    // Only check for warning messages if necessary
    if (severity == "good") {
        for(var warningMessagesItem in warningMessages) {
            if (message.indexOf(warningMessages[warningMessagesItem]) != -1) {
                severity = "warning";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    postData.attachments = [
        {
            "color": severity,
            "fields": fields
        }
    ];

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        hostname: 'hooks.slack.com',
        port: 443,
        path: services  // Defined above
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        context.done(null);
      });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    req.write(util.format("%j", postData));
    req.end();
};
```

Comment: Detail tutorial to implement this nodejs lambda function is here.https://anattaguy.medium.com/slack-notifications-for-aws-codedeploy-events-b2a771f29e8d thanks @nonbeing

Answer (score 1):

At a high-level you need to:

- Setup an SNS topic
- Create a CodeDeploy Trigger
- Add `sns:Publish` permissions to the CodeDeploy IAM Role
- Configure Slack with an Incoming Webhook
- Write and configure a Lambda function to process CodeDeploy's SNS messages, construct Slack messages and send them to Slack at the Incoming Webhook

I used code similar to the gist above to setup a Lambda function for Slack notifications for CodeDeploy events. I documented the entire procedure, including screenshots [over here](https://medium.com/@nonb3ing/slack-notifications-for-aws-codedeploy-events-b2a771f29e8d).

I couldn't find a similar, end-to-end guide elsewhere so I hope this helps someone else who stumbles on this question.

Comment: The details linked helped a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no native solution, there is a workaround that you can employ to accomplish this. You can use lambda to trigger these events. On the AWS blog, they show on how to trigger codedeploy via lambda when you upload a file to S3 (https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx3TPMTH0EVGA64/Automatically-Deploy-from-Amazon-S3-using-AWS-CodeDeploy). Using this same concept, you can have your lambda function listen to a error/success bucket, and modify your codedeploy package to upload a file to s3 which in turn you can use as an event trigger to send an email via SES (https://peekandpoke.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/dancing-the-lambada-with-aws-lambda-or-sending-emails-on-s3-events/) or contact a web service/page that does what you want. It might be a little hokey but it gets the job done.

Comment: I don't think you know the deployment succeeded/failed by extending the deployment itself (you even introduce another error source into the deployment). Or am I misreading your answer?

Comment: At the end of the deployment you can spawn off a powrshell script since the deployment knows its own Id. You have it wait like a minute then have it query the status of it. You can even do this up front and have it query the status of the deployment. Here's a link to the powrshell cmdlet that returns back the status. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-CDDeployment.html its not elegant but it gets the job done.